# In Rails, can you set flash[:error] when calling link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For instance, let's say I have the following:

```
link_to 'Page', page_path(foobar)
```

Is there a way to set flash[:error] in the link_to call that will be displayed at `page_path`?

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
link_to 'Page', page_path(foobar), :error => "Flash message"
```

Comment: It is unclear what your error condition is. Do you want to show error message when link is bad? In any case this should be handled by the `controller` that is handling your link.

Comment: Let's say that I have a website about cars and a page that contains a list of links. When clicked, each link will send you to a page that gives you the information about a specific car. If an admin clicks the "Car X" link, and there is information about Car X in the database, they'll be redirected to the page that displays it. If they click the "Car Y" link, and it has no information regarding it in the database, I want to send the user to the page that lets them edit the information, as well as flash a message that says something like "This car doesn't have any information. Please add some."

Answer (score 3):

In your controller that responds to the link you should do `flash[:error] = message`. It should be in the same place where you decide if you need to redirect your admin to the `edit` page. Once again it is in the `controller` and not in your `view`

Answer (score 1):

You should set flash[:error] in the controller but you could make it use a param you send it in the link if you want.  Move the :error option into the route call:

```
link_to 'Page', page_path(foobar, :error => "Flash message")
```

Then in the controller, i you don't find the resource or whatever, you could say

flash[:error] = params[:error] || "Sorry, we couldn't find that page"

The problem with this is that the param will show up in the url, so you will have a url of (eg)

```
"/pages/123?error=Flash%20message
```

or something like that.